# Will Ubuntu one sync if I update files in my local directory?

Tags: ubuntu-one, cloud, sync

If I change a file in my local ubuntu One directory:

- Will it be sync to the cloud server?
- Will this file be updated on another PC's ubuntu one directory ?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu One allows synchronization of files across machines and does this by synchronizing any file you put in the ~/Ubuntu One folder.

Comment: Ubuntu One will also allow you to mark any other folder as a synced folder and then also synchronize that, so you could set your "Documents" or "Music" folder to sync.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it must be if you synced that to PCs ubuntu one folders.

Answer (score 0):

> Will it be sync to the cloud server?

Yes, Ubuntu one automatically syncs files in your local directory with the files in cloud.

> Will this file be updated on another PC's ubuntu one directory ?

This will only happen, if you or someone logged in to that PC and Ubuntu one service starts.