# Can I force Ubuntu One to sync a file?

Tags: ubuntu-one, sync

I set up the `Documents` folder to sync in Ubuntu One a few months ago. Last week I made some modifications to a file in that folder.

According to this question [`Will Ubuntu one sync if I update files in my local directory?`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/110900/will-ubuntu-one-sync-if-i-update-files-in-my-local-directory), I understand that Ubuntu One is supposed to sync my modifications.

But now, I've set up Ubuntu One on another system in order to sync the folder. But I've found out that my modification weren't uploaded to Ubuntu One, as I received the older, unmodified version of my file.

So my question, since that file wasn't updated, is there a way to find out if there were any other files that also weren't updated and can I force them to be synced and updated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.Disconnect from Ubuntu One.(Device tab in Ubuntu One)

2.Connect to Ubuntu One.

When You reconnect all files will synchronize.

https://one.ubuntu.com/help/faq/how-can-i-force-ubuntu-one-to-sync-my-files/